# Hide all but $(this) via :not in jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

Advanced title, simple question:

How can I do the following in jQuery (hiding everything except `$(this)`)?

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
    $("table tr:not(" + $(this) + ")").hide();
    // $(this) is only to illustrate my problem

    $("table tr").show();
});
```

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
$(this).siblings().hide();
```

[Traversing/Siblings](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings)

Answer (score 159):

```
$("table.tr").not(this).hide();
```

---

As an aside, I think you mean `$("table tr")` (with a space instead of a dot).
The way you have it, it selects every table which has a class of `tr` (eg, `<table class="tr">`), which is probably not what you want.

For more information, see the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Comment: Yeah, it was a mistake with the dot. I somehow fail to see how this is easier than Alexanders solution, which seems more clean. I know i asked how to do it with :not, but the siblings method just seems more clean.

Comment: Just to add, if you're clicking something within the table to try and get it to hide all the table rows EXCLUDING the row containing the item you clicked, use: `$('tr').not($(this).closest('tr')).hide();`

Comment: This is useful for selecting specific elements, in case the structure is more complex than siblings would allow. I'm having a hard time coming up with an example, but perhaps something where you want to hide things inside a grid, but not the grid itself.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to combine not() with some other selectors, you can use add():

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  $('a').not(this).add('#someID, .someClass, #someOtherID').animate({'opacity':0}, 800);
});
```

This would fadeout all other links, but the clicked one, and additionally fadeout some chosen ids and classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution can be this:

```
$("table.tr").click(function() {
    $("table.tr:not(" + $(this).attr("id") + "").hide(); // $(this) is only to illustrate my problem
    $(this).show();
})
```

--EDIT for Comment:

```
$("table.tr").click(function() {
    $("table.tr:not(#" + $(this).attr("id") + ")").hide(); // $(this) is only to illustrate my problem
    $(this).show();
})
```

Comment: You mean `:not(#" + ...`.  Also, this won't work unless the element has an ID, which is unlikely.

Comment: this would require you to add random and unnecessary ids onto all your table rows (or whatever you're using).

Comment: @ SLaks, Thanks for the correction. On the dow, you may have in mind that sometimes what we seek is to have a Quick Answers to help. Why not take lightly what we put.

Comment: @nickf, Yes, you're right, but that comment would be good first asking a @Kordonme if they have ID for each TR.