# Toggle between variables (changing after being clicked once)

Tags: jquery, variables, toggle

I'm trying to toggle between the content stored in a variables.
In start position all content is shown.
When click on (lets say) option1 the content of option2 should hide and the content for option1 should still be shown.
When then clicked on option2 , option1 should be kept shown and content for option2 should re-appear.
After that both should act like a "normal" toggle for there own content.

So the var option1 and 2 are the content for the a tags 1 & 2.

```
<ul class="thera-nav">
<li><a href="#">option1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">option2</a></li>
<ul> 

var option1 = $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='sporttherapie']");
var option2 = $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='massagetherapie']");

$('.thera-nav a').click(function() {
e.preventDefault(); 
//show this? and hide others only first time?
});
```

Below I found an answer who is in the right direction, but I can't get right it for this case.
[Hide all but $(this) via :not in jQuery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328314/hide-all-but-this-via-not-in-jquery-selector)?

Someone got a clue how to get it right?

The code in the response below I could t get to work, but with a bit a tweaking I've almost got it to work.
When clicking option 1, option 1 is shown and option two is hide. What i miss is this case clicking two times option 1. 1st: hide two show one. second time: let reappear option 1. now its only 1 or 2:

```
$('.thera-nav a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var str = $(this).text();
if (str == 'sporttherapie')
{
var option= $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='sporttherapie']");
}

else if (str == 'massagetherapie')
{
var option= $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='massagetherapie']");
}
option.siblings().hide();
option.show();
```

Comment: How can you click **Option2** when it's not shown?

Comment: The menu ("thera-nav") of the a tags should all ways be there. Its  the content stored in the variables who should be toggled (by menu click).

Comment: @Rob: When you refer to variables, you mean actual Javascript variables or DIVs?

Comment: The DIVS. "$('div[class^="cn-list-row"]')"

Comment: The DIVs. All the div->classes starting with "cn-list-row" containing "sporttherapie"(opt1) or "massagetherapie"(opt2) should be shown as default. But clicking option1 (a tag) should hide option2(DIV) and keep showing opt1(DIV). If you than click option2, 1 should stay and 2 reappear. I guess this is how browsing on ebay works as well.

Comment: @Rob: I don't see where eBay works this way, but nevermind. Do those options have a checkbox or something or are they just some menu items you can click and they show other elements (as you say DIVs)? If they're implemented as toggle elements (ie. checkboxes) what happens when you first select option1 and then instead of selecting option2, you deselect option1 again?

Comment: @Rob: It would be much easier to understand if you'd provide a JSFiddle with your mark-up so we could actually see what you're trying to work on... Because the way that you describe the problem is rather hard to understand or at least I'm having difficulties understanding it...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thera-nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch $(this).text() {
        case 'option 1':
            var option = $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='sporttherapie']");
            break;
        case 'option 2':
            var option = $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='massagetherapie']");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    option.siblings().hide();
    option.show();
    $(this).unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
        switch $(this).text() {
            case 'option 1':
                var option = $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='sporttherapie']");
                break;
            case 'option 2':
                var option = $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='massagetherapie']");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        option.toggle();
    });
});
```

I guess this is what you want.

Comment: ty. I'm slowly analysing how this script works. It seems like a clever solution. I just tried to run the code but i get an error on line3 the first "switch $(this).text() { ". but I cant see why the error is there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it can be written shorter and more effectively, but it does what I meant. First click it hides all but clicked. And then everything toggles like normal.

```
<div id="therapie">
 <ul class="thera-nav">
<li><a href="#" class='on'>sporttherapie</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='on'>massagetherapie</a></li>
ul>
</div>
```

.

```
$('.thera-nav a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var sporttherapie = $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='blub']");
var massagetherapie = $('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter("[class*='bla']");

var str = $(this).text();
if (str == 'sporttherapie' && $(this).hasClass('on'))
{
var option= sporttherapie
option.siblings().hide();
$('.thera-nav a').removeClass().addClass('of');
}

else if (str == 'massagetherapie' && $(this).hasClass('on'))
{
var option= massagetherapie
option.siblings().hide();
$('.thera-nav a').removeClass().addClass('of');
}

else if (str == 'sporttherapie' && $(this).hasClass('of'))
{
var option= sporttherapie
option.toggle();
}

else if (str == 'massagetherapie' && $(this).hasClass('of'))
{
var option= massagetherapie
option.toggle();
}

return false;

});
```